# Trying to take input in Switch case of Java, but showing me another result. What is the specific problem here?

Tags: java, input, switch-statement

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Dx {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
        String day = myObj.nextLine();
        if (day == "morning") {
            System.out.println("Good Morning");
        } else if (day == "afternoon") {
            System.out.println("Good Afternoon");
        } else if (day == "evening") {
            System.out.println("Good evening!");
        } else if (day == "night") {
            System.out.println("Good night");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Good Day");
        }
    }
}
```

Here the output shows Good Day when giving night or morning.

Comment: Comparing strings in java is your google keyword.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Also, you are using an `if-else` cascade, not `switch-case`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments above:

```
    Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);
    String day = myObj.nextLine();
    switch(day) {
        case "morning" :
            System.out.println("Good Morning"); break;
        case "afternoon":
            System.out.println("Good Afternoon"); break;
        case "evening":
            System.out.println("Good evening!"); break;
        case "night" :
            System.out.println("Good night"); break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Good Day");
    }
```

Comment: Good suggestion. But you should have address the issue of OP first

Comment: What is OP?  This is a solution to the problem presented, is it not?

Answer (score -1):

Strings in java are best compared by the .equals() method.

```
if (stringA.equals(stringB)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please, don't answer questions that are clearly duplicate :)